# MySQL on duplicate key update is not updating

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-key

I'm trying to use on duplicate key update but it's not affecting any rows.

My table create statement, where you can see that I've created a unique key on childid and date.

```
CREATE TABLE `history_childfees` (
    `childid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `feetypecode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `key_childdate` (`childid`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

These are the two rows I have in the table.

[image]

The row I'm trying to update is the first row, by changing the amount for child 86615 on 2019-03-22.

```
insert into history_childfees (childid,date,amount,feetypecode)
values(86615,'2019-03-22',50,'DAY')
on duplicate key update childid = 86615, date = '2019-03-22';
```

I've also tried this syntax.

```
insert into history_childfees (childid,date,amount,feetypecode)
values (86615,'2019-03-22',50,'DAY')
on duplicate key update childid = values(childid), date = values(date);
```

Either way, it does not perform an insert and there's no error when I execute but it affects 0 rows.  What am I missing here?

Comment: So you're trying to change it to what it already is?

Comment: No, I'm trying to change the amount to 50.

Comment: So now you know what to do.

Comment: I get it.  I thought the columns after "key update" were supposed to be the key columns, but they're actually the columns I want to update.  Strange syntax.

Comment: Actually, something strange happens when I run this on my server. !?!?!

Comment: Oh, nevermind - i typed an 8 where I should have typed a 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE `history_childfees` (
    ...  
    UNIQUE KEY `key_childdate` (`childid`,`date`)
);
```

And:

```
insert into history_childfees
...
on duplicate key update childid = 86615, date = '2019-03-22'
```

The columns that you update on duplicate key are exactly those of the `UNIQUE KEY` that you are using to identify duplicates. By design, we already know that the values do match... As a consequence, the query leaves duplicate records unmodified.

If I followed you correctly, you probably want:

```
insert into history_childfees
...
on duplicate key update amount = 50
```

Comment: Yes, I wasn't understanding the syntax correctly.  Thank you.